# Convert This Sql to Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I create this query with Eloquent?

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `contents` 
WHERE
    `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT
        `id` 
    FROM
        `contents` AS `laravel_reserved_0` 
    WHERE
        `laravel_reserved_0`.`parent_id` IN ( 
            SELECT
                `id` 
            FROM
                `contents` AS `laravel_reserved_1` 
            WHERE
                `laravel_reserved_1`.`type` IN ( 'pro' )
            ) 
    ) 
AND `is_active` = 1 
AND `type` IN ( 'stars', 'video', 'article' )
GROUP BY
    `slug` 
ORDER BY
    `created_at` DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: By using their documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple queries, separate for nested queries.

```
$typeIDs = Content::whereIn('type', ['pro'])->pluck('id');

$parentIDs = Content::whereIn('parent_id', $typeIDs)->pluck('id');

$contents = Content::whereNotIn('id', $parentIDs)
    ->where('is_active', 1)
    ->whereIn('type', ['stars', 'video', 'article'])
    ->groupBy('slug')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Beside this, if you wish, you can also replace created variables with the actual queries itself.